# ShaderEffectSource doesn't respect scale of source item

Tags: qt, qml

I use ShaderEffectSource to cache some UI items which works fine if the scale property of the source item is 1.0. If I change the scale of source item to something else, ShaderEffectSource doesn't respect it :

```
Row {
    spacing: 100

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        scale: 2.0
        color: "blue"
        width: 50
        height: 50

        Text {
            text: "TEST"
            color: "white"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        sourceItem: rect
        live: true
        width: rect.width
        height: rect.height
        // hideSource: true
    }
}
```

[image]

If I apply the same scale value to ShaderEffectSource then it just interpolates it which results in lower resolution copy:

[image]

So the question is, how can I get a properly scaled render of the source item ?

Comment: try `recursive: true`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `scale` property does not affect `height` and `width` properties.

If you want to get the correct size for your ShaderEffectSource, you need to multiply with the scale value:

```
ShaderEffectSource {
    sourceItem: rect
    live: true
    width: rect.width * rect.scale
    height: rect.height * rect.scale
}
```

P.S.: `Scale` property scales from item's origin. You're going to have a difference between you ShaderEffectSource top and your rect top. Using a RowLayout may position correctly both your elements.

Comment: This is same as scaling ShaderEffectSource. It doesn't render the source item in its scaled form. Just interpolates it.

Answer (score 0):

QML properties such as `scale`, `rotation`, or arbitrary `transform` can be conceptually understood to apply on the "outside" of the `Item`. They affect how the item is presented (and processes input) in the enclosing scope, but don't affect the item itself. This has various subtle effects, such as - in your example - the `Row` container will not consider the scaled size of the item, and will place other items relative to the original size.

So, in order to capture a scaled item in a `ShaderEffectSource`, you can simply enclose it in another item, for example:

```
Row {
    spacing: 100
    Item {
        id: rectContainer
        width: 100
        height: 100
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            scale: 2.0
            color: "blue"
            width: 50
            height: 50
            // I've added this to ensure that the
            // scaled item is positioned correctly in the container
            transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft 

            Text {
                text: "TEST"
                color: "white"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        sourceItem: rectContainer
        live: true
        width: rectContainer.width
        height: rectContainer.height
        // hideSource: true
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you simply want to obtain a higher-resolution texture, you can leave the item at the original size and specify the texture size explicitly in ShaderEffectSource:

```
    ShaderEffectSource {
        sourceItem: rect
        live: true
        width: rect.width*2
        height: rect.height*2
        textureSize: Qt.size(width,height)
    }
```